# Replace only the first occurence matching a regex with sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a string

```
test:growTest:ret
```

And with sed i would to delete only test: to get :

```
growTest:ret
```

I tried with

```
sed '0,/RE/s/^.*://'
```

But it only gives me

```
ret
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want strings like `test:growTest:ret` to become `growTest:ret`.

You can use:

```
sed -i 's/test:(.*$)/\1/'
```

*i* means edit in place.

s/one/two/ replaces occurences of *one* with *two*.

So this replaces "test:(.*$)" with "\1". Where \1 is the contents of the first group, which is what the regex matched inside the braces.

"test:(.*$)" matches the first occurence of "test:" and then puts everything else until the end of the line unto the braces. The contents of the braces remain after the sed command.

Comment: Does this require a particular version of sed. I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 16: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS` when i try that one.

Comment: There looks to be a bug in the answer. Isn't it `sed -i 's/test:\(.*$\)/\1/'` instead? i.e. the selectors ( and ) always need a \ backslash prefix.

Answer (score 7):

Modify your regexp `^.*:` to `^[^:]*:`

All you need is that the `.*` construction won't consume your delimiter — the colon. To do this, replace matching-any-char `.` with negated brackets: `[^abc]`, that match any char *except* specified.

Also, don't confuse the two circumflexes `^`, as they have different meanings: first one matches beginning of string, second one means negated brackets.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sed use hungry match. So `^.*:` will match `test:growTest:` other than `test:`.
2. Default, sed only replace the first matched pattern. So you need not do anything specially.